# How do you configure JRE-related error messages in Install4j

Tags: install4j

We have an installer with a bundled JRE. Since we want users to only use the bundled JRE we have turned off all entries from "JRE search sequence". However that creates some unfortunate error messages. E.g. if the bundled JRE is removed the user gets a message about defining "EXE4J_JAVA_HOME", we would prefer a message just telling the user that the bundled JRE is missing. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the General Settings->Languages step, set up a custom localization file, then open the built-in editor and click on the "Override messages" tool bar button. Search for the message you want to change and click on OK. Then you can change the text in the editor.